# About casting sub-class to super-class in JAVA

Tags: java

```
public class Car {

    String color;

    public void thisIs(){
        System.out.println("Calling method from Car: the color is " + color);
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public class BMW extends Car {

    public void thisIs(){
        System.out.println("Calling method from BMW: the color is " + color);
    }
    public Car toCar(){
    Car newCar = new Car();
    newCar.setColor(this.color);
    return newCar;
}

}

public class AbstractTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Car aCar = new Car();
        aCar.setColor("Red");
        aCar.thisIs();

        BMW aBMW = new BMW();
        aBMW.setColor("Black");
        aBMW.thisIs();

        //Car aaCar = new Car();
        //aaCar = (Car)aBMW;
        //aaCar.thisIs();

            Car aaCar = aBMW.toCar();
    aaCar.thisIs();
    }
}
```

I expect the result to be:

> Calling method from Car: the color is Red
>
> Calling method from BMW: the color is Black
>
> Calling method from Car: the color is Black

But, the result I got is:

> Calling method from Car: the color is Red
>
> Calling method from BMW: the color is Black
>
> Calling method from BMW: the color is Black

Where am I wrong? 
And how can I use the method from the super class to get the data in a subclass object?
I can write a `toCar()` method in BMW class to do this. 
But, why casting doesn't work?
Thanks ahead!

OK! Thank you!

I got why casting doesn't work.

So, I add a method in BMW toCar() to get the result I want.

Comment: This is basic OOP, you might want to read a good book

Comment: I like how this tutorial explains it: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/cannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/14%20Java%20Upcasting%20Downcasting.htm

Comment: Yes. The link explains what I misunderstood. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Casting the object does not change the nature of the object.  It is still a BMW object; casting just tells the compiler to treat it as though it were a Car object.

As long as we're on the subject of inheritance: there is NO need to put either the color variable or the get/setColor methods into both the super and subclass.  Putting them in the car class means they are available in any subclass; they are superfluous and a bit confusing in the subclass.  I would take them out entirely.

Comment: If I have a sub-class object. Is there a way to "talk" to this object through super class method? While the sub-class doesn't have a toCar() method?

Comment: I'm not positive what you mean by "talk to" - a superclass method is callable on all subclass objects, and executes the code defined in the superclass. So you can call setColor() and getColor() on BMW, and they behave just the same as if called on a Car instance or an instance of any other subclass of Car (at least, any subclass that doesn't redefine those methods). This behavior is at the root of OO design; BMW is a "special case of Car", and is therefore expected to behave like a Car plus whatever is defined for a BMW.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the runtime polymorphism. The last statement is because even if you have a car reference pointing to the BMW object(by casting you are not modifying the nature of the object! BMW will still be a BMW it does not become Car object!), Ultimately its the BMW's thisIs() method that will be called! This is know as [Dynamic Method Dispatch](http://www.java2all.com/1/1/11/56/Technology/CORE-JAVA/Inheritance/Dynamic-Method-Dispatch)

Comment: What is it? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: please read about  Dynamic Method Dispatch! and Think of objects this way: A super class object is of higher datatype and sub class object is of lower datatype! for example in terms of primitives, short is a lower data type compared to an int which is of higher data type. Just because you up cast(widen) a short variable to a int, does not mean that the contents in the short variable changes!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I understand the concept of polymorphism. And, my misunderstanding here is casting. I thought that the result of (Car)aBMW would be a Car object. But, just like Ben Zotto and rcook said. The casting doesn't even change what the object is.

Answer (score 1):

The BMW is still a BMW even if you call it a car.

The cast doesn't change what the object is. It just tells the compiler how you intend to treat it. You created a BMW, and it's still one when you call its `thisIs` method.

Answer (score 0):

Well You don't need to `explicitly cast` the `BMW object` to a Car type, because a `BMW object` is a `subclass of Car and a Car can be of any type` (a BMW or anything). So when you assign the `BMW object to a car the implicit casting is done` by the compiler. In your case you are `explicitly asking the compiler to cast the BMW object to car type`.

Also this implicit casting doesn't mean that the BMW object will loose its `thisIs()` method or any other property.

Answer (score -1):

Consider following code:

```
public void someMethod(Car c) {
  c.thisIs(); 
}
```

'c' can hold reference of all subclasses. Whichever reference is hold by 'c', that method will be called. Its also called runtime polymorphism.