# what will happen if subclass object is casted to superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Base {
    void test() {
        System.out.println("base");
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    void test() {
        System.out.println("derived");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        Base b = (Base) d;
        b.test();
    }
}
```

o/p: derived

why? If I cast a subclass object to super class object super class object will refer to subclass object only?

Comment: Do you mean the println from b.test() prints "derived"? No matter what reference type you use to store the reference the actual object is still of type derived. This information is used when making the call at runtime.

Comment: thanks onesixtyfourth,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting doesn't change the object at all. The result is just a reference to the same object, but with a different compile-time type. Casting to a super-type can't fail, it can *only* make a difference to the compile-time type of the expression, which can occasionally be useful for overload resolution.

In the same way, casting from an expression of a superclass type to a subclass type will never create a new object - it just checks whether the cast is valid, and the result is a reference to the same object as before, but in an expression with the subclass type. This is useful more often than casting to the superclass, as it gives you access to more members (usually). For example:

```
String text1 = "hello";
System.out.println(text1.length());

Object object = (Object) text1; // Or just Object object = text1;
// object.length() would be invalid...

String text2 = (String) object;
// text2.length() is valid again
System.out.println(text2.length());
```

The values of `text1`, `object` and `text2` are all the same: a reference to the *single* string object which is used throughout the example.

Answer (score 1):

Derived object is also a Base object, when you cast it you only change the "view" I mean: You can use every method of Base but not of Derived because you see it as a Base object not as a Derived object. When you call a method casted to Base will be called his method but it's a derived object not a  Base object (in memory it's always a Derived object) so it will see his method.

In summary: In memory you will always have a Derived object, you will just see it as a Base object and you are limited to Base methods (you cannot use Derived methods)

Answer (score 0):

Then you can access only the methods of super class only and similar methods(defined in both) will be overrided with the one in subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the object does not change the nature of the object.
Have you tried to look at this post ? You may find answers to your questions.

[About casting sub-class to super-class in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151013/about-casting-sub-class-to-super-class-in-java)